# How to keep only the first and last item of a pandas groupby join

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following `df`:

```
pd.DataFrame({'x':['bob','bob','bob','amy','amy','amy'],'y':['keep this','not this','keep this','keep this','not this','keep this']})


     x  y
0   bob keep this
1   bob not this
2   bob keep this
3   amy keep this
4   amy not this
5   amy keep this
```

And I want to group by `x`, and join `y`. However, I only want the first and last items of the join.

Doing a basic group by join, this is the result:

```
df.groupby('x').agg({'y':', '.join})

          y
x   
amy keep this, not this, keep this
bob keep this, not this, keep this
```

However, my desired output is below:

```
          y
x   
amy keep this, keep this
bob keep this, keep this
```

Is there a way I can do this programmatically? I tried using some indexing and slicing tricks as part of the join but got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

It would be really nice if there were a way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can groupby twice, once to keep first/last, and once for your aggregation:

```
(df.groupby('x', as_index=False)
   .apply(lambda d: d.iloc[[0,-1]])
   .groupby('x')
   .agg({'y':', '.join})
)
```

output:

```
                        y
x                        
amy  keep this, keep this
bob  keep this, keep this
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the first and last appearences in the `groupby`:

```
df.drop_duplicates('x', keep='first').append(df.drop_duplicates('x', keep='last')).groupby('x').agg({'y':', '.join})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby.first` and `groupby.last`, concatenate them into a dataframe and apply `groupby` again with the `join`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['bob','bob','bob','amy','amy','amy'],'y':['keep this','not this','keep this','keep this','not this','keep this']})
df

# Define groups of x values.
g = df.groupby('x')

g.first().append(g.last()).groupby('x').agg({'y': ', '.join})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

1. [`GroupBy.first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) + [`GroupBy.last()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html).
2. Join them by `+`
3. convert resulting series to dataframe by [`.to_frame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html)

as follows:

```
(df.groupby('x')['y'].first() + ', ' + df.groupby('x')['y'].last()
).to_frame()
```

**Result:**

```
                        y
x                        
amy  keep this, keep this
bob  keep this, keep this
```